# I have images in my public folder in React application, but I am unable to access images folder from public folder

Tags: reactjs

I cannot access images from public folder into my React application.

```
const Menu = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image:"images/maggi.jpg",
        name: "Maggi",
        category: "Breakfast",
        price: 30,
        description: "Hi please select maggi here"
    },
]
```

Comment: Please take a moment to practice with the editor, so that posts (and code) are formatted in a readable fashion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a `/` before `images/maggi.jpg` like this ->

```
const Menu = [ 
    { 
        id: 1, 
        image:"/images/maggi.jpg", 
        name: "Maggi", 
        category: "Breakfast", 
        price: 30, 
        description: "Hi please select maggi here" 
    }, 
]
```

To access the public directory, you need to put a `/` before the path

Comment: It would be helpful if you also add info about Relative paths and Absolute paths too.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you can try using require method...

```
    const Menu = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image:require("../public/images/maggi.jpg"),
        name: "Maggi",
        category: "Breakfast",
        price: 30,
        description: "Hi please select maggi here"
    },
]
```